# How is de = 1 (mod ϕ(n)) calculated

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am reading RSA algorithm. So, I was writing a question but I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772063/to-solve-for-the-decryption-exponent-why-do-we-solve-the-congruence-de-1-mo) question and still couldn't understand it.

If $$e\cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)},$$ then 
$$ed=k\cdot \varphi(n)+1, \qquad k\in \mathbb{Z},$$

How did that first step turned to second step. Is that some kind of formula? Do, I need to cram it or there is some logic? I think of $1 (\bmod ~\varphi(n)) $ as  1 % $\varphi(n)$ which I quess must be very small as $\varphi(n)$ is very large

Here, $\varphi(n)$ is `(p-1)(n-1)` where p and q are both large prime numbers.

Also, where does this `k` come from in picture where k belongs to integer Z.

Comment: What do you thing $e\cdot d\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(n)}$ means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $a \equiv b \pmod{r}$ is defined to mean that $r$ divides the difference $a-b$.  Therefore, the equation $d\cdot e \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ is interpreted to mean that $\phi(n)$ divides the difference $d\cdot e - 1$.  This means that the difference, being a multiple of $\phi(n)$, is of the form $k \cdot \phi(n)$ for some integer $k$.  (This is where the $k$ comes in.)  Rearranging $d\cdot e - 1 = k\cdot \phi(n)$ yields $d\cdot e = 1 + k\phi(n)$, as desired.

You should think of $1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ as an equivalence class of all numbers of the form $\{ 1 + k\phi(n)\}$.  You don't really want to use your intuition about 'size' when thinking about modular arithmetic, which I view conceptually as due to the fact that you're using a number wheel (such as a clock, for mod $12$), as opposed to a number line.

Comment: you are quite right, it was initially an $n$, and I failed to notice that $k$ was hardly any better